# Complex Numbers to real powers.

Tags: complex-analysis

I can't seem to find a definitive answer to this, or get my head around it since hearing the definition of complex numbers raised to complex powers.  If I raised a complex power to a real number, does it follow the same exponentiation rules as a real number would. Or do you have to do it using a branch of logarithm ?

Comment: $(a+bi)^n=a^n+na^{n-1}bi-\frac {n(n-1)}{2!} a^{n-2}b+\ldots$

Comment: You are searching for $(a+ib)^p$ where $a,b,p$ are real numbers, what do you think? It is more convenient to use exponential form though, just as for complex powers $$(r e^{i s})^p=r^p e^{i s p}$$

Comment: The branches come into play when you consider, for example the real part $\cos(s)=\cos (s+2 \pi n)$ with $n$ an integer, which, after raising to power $p$ looks like: $\cos (sp) \quad ? \quad \cos (sp+2 \pi n p)$. Those two are not equal in general. If $p$ is, for example $1/2$, you get two different square roots. As you see, real powers can involve branches just as complex ones.

Comment: If $p$ in the above example is irrational, you actually get *infinitely many* (!) different answers. Which is why you have to pick some branch as the main one. In other words, things are just as complicated for real powers as for complex ones

Answer (score 0):

What's really the difference between raising a number to a real and to a complex power? Let's consider the general case:

In the following $r,s,p,q$ are all real.

$$(r e^{i s})^{p+iq}=r^{p}r^{iq} e^{i s p}e^{- s q}=r^{p}e^{- s q} e^{i (sp+ q \log r) }$$

$\log r$ is defined as usual for real numbers. So it's just another complex number with the modulus $r^{p}e^{- s q}$ and phase $sp+ q \log r$.

Now what about the branches?

As the complex exponential is periodic due to its trigonometric nature, we have: $$e^{is}=e^{i(s+2 \pi n)}, \quad n=0, \pm1, \pm 2,$$

This means basically that there's an infinite number of ways to represent *the same* complex number, or equivalently, *the same point in the complex plane*.

$$r e^{is}=r e^{is} e^{2 i \pi n}$$

We define them as equal for any integer $n$, because for all practical applications they are.

But now, that we raise this to a complex power, we have:

$$(r e^{is} e^{2 i \pi n})^{p+iq}=r^{p}e^{- s q} e^{i (sp+ q \log r) }e^{- 2 \pi n q} e^{2 i \pi p n}$$

Funny thing happened: we've got a real factor in our modulus, which depends on $n$, as well as a phase factor. It's clear that for integers $n \neq m$, in general:

$$(r e^{is} e^{2 i \pi n})^{p+iq} \neq (r e^{is} e^{2 i \pi m})^{p+iq}$$

Even though we had $r e^{is} e^{2 i \pi n}=r e^{is} e^{2 i \pi m}$.

Now there are some values of $p$ and $q$ where we can have only the limited number of different branches.

It's simple to figure them out: $p$ should be rational and $q$ should be $0$.

If $p$ is irrational, there's no integer $n$ such that $np$ is an integer too.

If $q$ is not $0$, then the real factor $e^{- 2 \pi n q}$ is going to have different values for different $n$, so we are going to have an infinity of branches too.

> Hence, I would say, the only difference between raising a number to a complex power, as opposed to the real one is that we always have an infinity of branches, while for some real powers we can have a finite number of them (like two square roots, or three cubic roots).

For a general power we need to pick a certain branch, usually $n=0$ is convenient, though not always.